# How to access init subcommand in github

Tags: git

I was creating my directory on terminal which is;

```
                mkdir root/my-repo
                cd root/my-repo
                root@shell:-my-repo# git init (//doesn't work)
```

Reinitialized existing Git repository in /root/my-repo/.git/ (error)
Can anyone explain what mistake I made and not not letting me in?
Thanks

Comment: /root/my-repo already has a git repository

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `git init` command, a hidden folder called `.git` is created in the directory. You can verify that by running `ls -a` inside `root/my-repo/`. If that is the case, you are good to go.

If for some reason you need to create the repo again, you can:

1. Create a new folder and run `git init`
2. Detele the `.git` inside `root/my-repo` and run `git init` again